# Increase timeout.rb timer within block

Tags: ruby, timeout

I'm communicating with an RS232 keypad that has an LCD. On each keypress I write the key that was pressed to the LCD to provide feedback to the user.

If no key is pressed within 10 seconds I'd like to abandon waiting for input.

I've written some code that will timeout if the user isn't done entering a multi-character value within 10 seconds, what I'd rather do is give the user another 10 seconds to complete input after each keypress.

Is this possible using `timeout.rb`?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'serialport'
require 'timeout'

sp = SerialPort.new('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)

sp.write("Input:")

begin
   timeout(10) do
      input = ""
      sp.each_byte do |byte|
         #call to increase timeout.rb timer would go here
         input << byte.chr
         sp.write("Input:" + input)
      end
   end
rescue Timeout::Error
   puts "Timed out!"
   exit
end

puts input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative way of achieving the desired effect by using `Threads` instead of `timeout.rb` but would be interested to learn alternative methods.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'serialport'

sp = SerialPort.new('/dev/tty.usbserial', 9600, 8, 1, SerialPort::NONE)

sp.write("Input:")

input = ""
timer = Time.now + 10

t = Thread.new do
  sp.each_byte do |byte|
    timer = Time.now + 10
    input << byte.chr
    sp.write("Input:" + input)
  end
end

t.kill unless Time.now < timer while t.alive?
```